# webview not POST immediately

Tags: android, webview

We have a strange problem and the below is the scenario.

1. The mobile app is a hybrid app which will open a web page from
   server in webview
2. The web page contains several fields and the "Submit" button.
3. After the input the data, the user can "submit" to post the data
4. the server will process the data and redirect to the response URL

Now we found that the code works good in native webview. But when migrated into Mobilefirst Platform (based on Cordova internally), click the "submit" button will not post the data immediately. The post happened after the "back" button is pressed.

Could someone please give some help?

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: What's a native webview? MFP also uses a "native webview". Test the same scenario in a pure Cordova application. If it is working as expected there as well, then we have something to may be related to MFP. Otherwise, this is not related to MFP.

Comment: Tested in pure Cordova and it works.

Comment: SiuTin, Thanks for checking. Please remove this question and open a PMR instead as this will require investigation by the development team.

Answer (score 0):

This may very well be a product defect. You need to open an IBM support ticket (PMR) in order to have this investigated and possibly corrected.